# Installing Blender on iMac OS X 10.10

Tags: installation

I installed Blender on my laptop (Windows 10) and things went well.

However, my desktop computer is an iMac (OS X 10.10 Yosemite). I have no understanding of the iMac -- at all. I read the answer to a previous question and read the guide to install on OS X.  I am totally lost.

Can you help me further?

I am familiar with GNU since I have used the GNAT developer.

Answer (score 1):

You just copy/place the Blender folder in your Applications folder. To start Blender open the folder inside Applications, double-click on Blender icon and that's it. You can also drag the Blender icon and put it in your Dock for easy access.